# Kinect USB 3.0 keeps reconnecting frequently

Tags: windows, usb, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

I'm working on a Kinect app, using a Kinect 2.0 for Xbox One on a Windows 10 PC. Now I have a problem using a new computer. Testing the Kinect with KinectStudio or any of the example programms, the Kinect keeps reconnecting frequently, as if you would pull out the usb cable and plug it in again.

If the Kinect is running I get the full 30 fps but mostly only for about 10 seconds before the connection is interrupted. 
There is no other device plugged in at the usb 3 ports and I tried all of the ports. The computer has an Intel 8 Series/C220 Series USB Chipset and I updated and reinstalled all the drivers. The Kinect Configuration Verifier showes a problem with the usb Controller: "Supported USB 3.0 port detected with unknown bandwidth. Kinect may or may not be compatible with your hardware."

Did anyone experienced something similarly or do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I didnt try yet Kinect v2 with Windows 10 but I think it won't work... also doublecheck your .NET framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Kinect has to be attached to a 3.0 port that has its own pcie channel.
If the usb isn't built into the motherboard and you don't have a 3.0 without anything else on the channel, then you'll need to get a pcie to usb 3.0 addition for your motherboard.

Comment: How can I tell if the USB has its own PCIe Channel on a laptop? All I know is there is only 1 USB on that side, but it is next to a SATA and an HDMI port...
I am asking bc I am also having this exact same problem

Comment: You have to dig through the manufacturing specs. Possibly email or call the manufacturer.